# Should we use present and past tense together in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-choice

I always get confused in these kinds of sentences when someone thinks in his mind.

1. He might be thinking that I also **got** these kinds of materials that's why he asked me
2. He might be thinking that I also **get** these kinds of materials that's why he asked me.

I want to make it clear that I also get these kinds of materials regularly.

If I use past tense then it feels like it happened only once before he was thinking and if I use present tense then it feels like it happens regularly.

Comment: He might be thinking about you with regard to a present or past tense. Do you get them all the time? Or did you get them once?

Comment: He thought - "Rocky gets these kinds of materials let me ask him".

Comment: Both are fine. He might be thinking that I also get [x at y, habitually] so that's why he asked me. OR He might be thinking that I also got [x at y, once] so that's why he asked me.